# R - create list by numeric sequence

Tags: r, list

I need to create a List as below:

```
 A = list(1,2,3,4)
```

The number of list elements is stored in a variable X (X=4 in this example). I tried using the below script but getting a different output

```
A = list(seq (1,X,1))
```

I get output as

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

.............................................................

I NEED output as below

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please have a look at this:

```
x<-4
as.list(seq (1,x,1))
```